# Boostrap Dropdown moves other divs down

Tags: css, html

When I click the dropdown button the other content under it moves down with it. The  I've tried z-index, position:relative; position:static How can I prevent this from happening. I don't want anything to move when the dropdown is clicked. Any ideas?

```
      <div class='whiteBox'>
            <div class='newProducts'></div>
            <div id="compareInfo">
               <div id="comparisionTitle">Title</div>
               <div class="divStyle">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                     <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="chooseItem">Drop down Box<span class="caret"></span></button>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a id="item1DropDown" href="#">item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="action-2">item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="action-3">item3</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /btn-group -->
               </div>
               <div id="compareBoxes">
                  <div id="Label">Text under Dropdown</div>
                  <button class=
                     "btn btn-compare" id="compareButton" type=
                     "submit">Submit</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

#divStyle{
    list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
        right:240px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the div you want to have a dropdown menu like this:

```
list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
```

And then set your own position for it.

[Here](http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/) is an excellent customizable tutorial on it.

Comment: In short, the parent container should have position relative and the container with the dropdown should have position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `dropdown` class on your div, and the role field for the `li` and `a` tags within your dropdown. Try adding `role="presentation"` to those.

Like:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"...>...</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="presentation ...>item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of a typical [bootstrap navbar dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) (in the documention you can see it working in the original navbar)

```
 <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

and when it's clicked it toogles `display:block` and the position is always

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
```

Since bootstrap highly depends on the it's markup you need to strictly reference the documentation, so I suggest you go over your code to see what's missing.